# Android media player(android.media.MediaPlayer) two music concurrently

Tags: android

Before open my application I played some of the music from default music player. With that background music I opened my application with the mediaplayer (android.media.MediaPlayer) to play the mp3 available in assets.

The default doesn't stop the music and I am getting two music concurrently from the device.

How do I stop or pause music of the default music player whenever my app started playing the music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thats impossible. The default music player is a different app and out of your control. android does not allow controlling other app features from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the info. if i use the videoview control to play the videos, the default music player paused the music. how it is possible??

Comment: can i use videoview to play the music??

Comment: You could try that if your requirement has no such restriction.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I was trying to stop the background music of the default music player (if it is playing) when my VoIP SIP application receives an incoming call.  I came up with:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

This does not stop or pause the music, but it make the music stream silent. Do not forget to unmute it later. This solution works well only if your second sound does not use the same stream.